# How to sort a list of strings based on how much a each string matches to a other sting in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, sorting

I'm new to Dart and Flutter. I have a list of strings which contains some paragraphs but I can't figure out how to sort the list based on how many words of each paragraph matches the words in string given by the user.

I have tried this but it seems I dons not work

`paras.sort((a, b) => b.contains(userPara).compareTo(a.contains(userPara));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you define "how much it matches".

If we say like you want to sort them based on who has the highest amount of equal characters to your `match` descending, then you would do the following:

```dart
  const String match = "123456";
  final List<String> paras = ["1", "123123", "1221222", "12341234", "12345", "121121", "123413"];

  paras.sort((String a, String b) {
    int matchCountA = 0;
    int matchCountB = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < match.length; ++i) {
      if (i < a.length && match[i] == a[i]) {
        matchCountA++;
      }
      if (i < b.length && match[i] == b[i]) {
        matchCountB++;
      }
    }
    if (matchCountA == matchCountB) {
      return 0;
    }
    return matchCountA > matchCountB ? -1 : 1;
  });

  print(paras); // [12345, 12341234, 123413, 123123, 1221222, 121121, 1]
```

The compare function should return a positive number if b is ordered before a and a negative number if a is ordered before b. Otherwise it should return 0.

Regarding your comment and edit, here is a similar function to sort the list by unique matched words this time **ascending**:

```dart
  const String match = "one two three four";
  final List<String> paras = ["one none", "one two two two", "one two three", "none", "one one", "one two three four"];

  paras.sort((String a, String b) {
    final Set<String> uniqueMatchWords = match.split(" ").toSet();
    final int uniqueWordsA = a.split(" ").toSet().where((String element) => uniqueMatchWords.contains(element)).length;
    final int uniqueWordsB = b.split(" ").toSet().where((String element) => uniqueMatchWords.contains(element)).length;
    return uniqueWordsA.compareTo(uniqueWordsB);
  });

  print(paras); // [none, one none, one one, one two two two, one two three, one two three four]
```

Comment: By how much I mean how many word from string give by the user matches the words in the list of paragraphs

Comment: Added another example in my answer to match by words instead of characters

Comment: No Problem at all